# iOS chrome automatically adds underline to email and phone number and makes it clickable

Tags: ios, iphone, google-chrome, underline

iOS chrome automatically adds underline to the **phone number and email and makes it clickable even though it is div** and I tried overwriting the style with **text-decoration: none!important;** but it didn't work.As there is no way to debug iOS chrome, I could not find the root cause.

Comment: I've just come across the same problem it's very annoying trying to write 123456789 as a tax number and it getting underlined as a hyperlink, if you don't define it why is Chrome doing this, very bad UX and invasive

Comment: This works in Safari but not Chrome: <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>